# Resetting a router with same name and password

Tags: wireless-networking, router, reset

If I would reset my router and set the name and password to exactly the same, would the devices that already saved the WiFi information connect to the router without any problems and without realizing it?

Comment: They should have no problem.  But many devices if they are turned on, will notice the network disappeared, at that point the behavior would be device specific.

Comment: yea, i know that. That doesn't really matter as this is just our home network, just wanna know if all our devices need to write password in again or not ;) and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the devices from noticing the network disappearing, you can turn them off before you reset the router. After you do all the updates to the router and ensure that the settings are exactly the same, turn the devices back on and all should be well.